# Courier IMAP stucks after authentication in Debian

Tags: debian, ldap, imap, courier

I just updated my Debian and Courier imap is not logging in anymore. Pop3 service works fine. In the logs I can see that authdaemon authenticates, but imapd gets stuck and does not return OK.

Logs:

```
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar authdaemond: received auth request, service=imap, authtype=login
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar authdaemond: authldap: trying this module
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar authdaemond: using search filter: (&(objectClass=CourierMailAccount)(uid=vsilva))
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar slapd[6421]: conn=1111 op=18 SRCH base="ou=users,dc=xxx,dc=com,dc=br" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=CourierMailAccount)(uid=vsilva))"
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar slapd[6421]: conn=1111 op=18 SRCH attr=homePostalAddress mailbox cn userPassword uid
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar slapd[6421]: conn=1111 op=18 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar authdaemond: one entry returned, DN: cn=Vagner Silva,ou=users,dc=xxx,dc=com,dc=br
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar authdaemond: authldaplib: sysusername=<null>, sysuserid=110, sysgroupid=115, homedir=/var/mail/imap/, address=vsilva, fullname=Vagner Silva, maildir=vsilva/, quota=<null>, options=<null>
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar authdaemond: password matches successfully
Jun 19 14:06:39 sylar authdaemond: Authenticated: sysusername=<null>, sysuserid=110, sysgroupid=115, homedir=/var/mail/imap/, address=vsilva, fullname=Vagner Silva, maildir=vsilva/, quota=<null>, options=<null>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what happened in this case, but one thing that could cause this is a misconfigured firewall that doesn't allow traffic on the loop-back interface. At least I've seen this happen on one of my servers.